# Unable to copy data from one table to a new table in MySQL due to a String - Date type clash

Tags: mysql

I've a date column in `table1` filled with character data that looks as follows:

```
InDate:
2022015
2012015
2122014
2112014
2102014
2092014
```

I've converted that data to following format:

```
InDate:
02-02-2015
02-01-2015
02-12-2014
02-11-2014
02-10-2014
02-09-2014
```

by using the following command:

```
update table1
set InDate = DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(InDate, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

But obviously this only changed the look of the string data in the `InDate` column. Now, this still didn't suffice my situation and I needed the column itself to be in `Date` type.

So, I created a new empty table called `table2` with the same structure as `table1` (except for `InDate` column, which I now declared as `Date` type) and tried copying the old data (which is having `InDate` in my required format (02-02-2015)).

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT *
FROM table1;
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '02-02-2015' for column 'InDate' at row 1
```

I need this column to be in Date type with the data intact. This table has millions of records that I need to work with. I really need to get around this error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 INSERT INTO table2(`InDate`)
SELECT CONCAT('\'',InDate,'\'')
FROM table1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry. This didn't work either. I found a way somewhere else where YYYY-MM-DD format was suggested instead of the one that I used. That solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code block maybe help use :

Not update table1.

`insert into table2
  (indate)
  select date_format(str_to_date(indate
                                ,'%d-%m-%Y')
                    ,'%d-%m-%Y')
    from table1;`